# How To Query Order By Desc StartDate But NULLS First

Tags: sql-server

[sQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ec1f6/5)

```
CREATE TABLE [STUDENT_MASTER]
(
   [User_ID]        [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT STUDENT_MASTER_P_KEY PRIMARY KEY,
   [Name]           [varchar] (50), 
   [START_DATE]     [varchar] (50),
   [PRIORITY]       [varchar] (50) 
)

INSERT INTO STUDENT_MASTER
VALUES('JOHN','2013-08-16','4')
INSERT INTO STUDENT_MASTER
VALUES('JACK','2013-08-10','')
INSERT INTO STUDENT_MASTER
VALUES('MACK','','1')
INSERT INTO STUDENT_MASTER
VALUES('ACK','2013-08-15','2')

//SQL QUERY

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
(ORDER BY CASE 
WHEN STUDENT_MASTER.START_DATE IS NULL THEN 1
WHEN STUDENT_MASTER.PRIORITY IS NULL THEN 1 
ELSE 0 END,STUDENT_MASTER.START_DATE DESC ,STUDENT_MASTER.PRIORITY DESC
)AS RowNumber,STUDENT_MASTER.START_DATE
FROM STUDENT_MASTER
```

HOW TO QUERY ORDER BY DESC START DATE AND NULL VALUE BE FIRST

Comment: There is a [data type designed specifically for dates](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: and [numbers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848794(v=sql.105).aspx)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ec1f6/29)

```
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN START_DATE = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC,
  START_DATE DESC
```

You could use `ISNULL`, but your column does not have `null` values - it has empty strings intead.

And another problem - because your `START_DATE` column is `VARCHAR`, not `DATETIME` it will perform string, alphabetical sort instead of datetime sorting.

Comment: Good observation , in this case I would suggest him to use nulls

Comment: Marcin i have one quetion

Answer (score 0):

Don't simply order by `StartDate`, order by `StartDate` or a default value if it's null.

```
ORDER BY ISNULL(StartDate, '9999-12-31') DESC
```

Oh... and have your date be an actual datetime. Otherwise you'll just be doing an alphabetical sort.

Comment: The value is not really `null`, it's an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that is for purpose your date as string, this would be my solution for the problem

```
SELECT
     start_date
FROM
     STUDENT_MASTER
ORDER BY
     LEN(start_date),
     start_date DESC
```

Follows the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ec1f6/49)

Comment: The value is not really `null`, it's an empty string.

Comment: Indeed it was, I edited assuming string as on purpose and gave other approach.